# html template in jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

This is a very short example, but I was wondering if there is a way of using an xml or html file with html markup instead of including it in the javascript like I do below.

I know there are template libraries out there, but I really just want to do something simple and not involve any libraries other than jQuery.

```
var description = this.name;

if description == 'full') {
    return "<div><textarea cols='50' rows='50'>" + this.value + "</textarea></div>";
} else {
    return "<div><textarea cols='50' rows='15'>" + this.value + "</textarea></div>";
};
```

Thanks

Comment: do you mean I should Google "ajax" to find my answer? Thanks

Comment: and probably implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, without a template engine you have three options:

a) Adding the template directly into your markup as script tag

```
<script type="text/template" data-template="stats">
   <div id="content">
      ...
   </div>
</script>
```

The html code inside the script tag could be accessed with the following code:

```
$("script[data-template=" + templateName + "]").html()
```

The big benefit of this approach is that you are not making another http request.

b) Putting the template in external file and load it via ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html"
}).done(function(html) {
    ...
});
```

c) Doing the things like you already did.

Comment: Option A looks good.  How would one access elements between the <script> tags?  Like my example above, say I had a textarea that I needed to fill with data...how would you access the <textarea>?  Thanks, your post was really helpful.

Comment: Once you get the html from the script tag you may construct another jquery object like that *var element = $(html)*. Then use the *.find* method to get a reference to the textarea: *element.find("textarea")*

Answer (score 1):

If you use AJAX to call a file, you can use the result of the file, which could be XML or nested HTML, etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

I define a hidden div on my markup - then give it a generic ID, then in javascript I use the jQuery.clone() method to make a clone of that markup, and in the markup I define the template macro values that can then be injected with the real data using .replace..

HTML:

```
<div id="mytemplate">
Name: {0}
</div>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
var clone = $('#mytemplate').clone();
```

Then perform the replacements on the clone object and simply append to the DOM where desired!